# URL won't jump to hash with on(click, function) handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have this code:

```
$("a[data-action='sale'").on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    StateMaster.togglehorseFilters('for_sale');
});
```

Basically I am just trying to pre-fire a filter on my forum when a user clicks on it but still take them to the section of the page where the content is.

The hash jump works and then pre-filtering works but the page won't navigate to the hash when I try and piggyback on the click event.

Update:

Some requested to see the `togglehorseFilters` method:

```
togglehorseFilters: function(filter) {
    this.state.horseFilters[filter].value = !this.state.horseFilters[filter].value;
    this.emit('horse-search-term-visibility-change');
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget the `]` in your selector.

```
$("a[data-action='sale']").on('click', function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('href');
  StateMaster.togglehorseFilters('for_sale');   
});
```

Comment: Correct! But also didn't fix the problem. Bummer.

Comment: @motleydev what is togglehorseFilters doing? Does it work if you remove that function call?

Comment: agree to @mattsven, please share this code to help you.

Comment: doesn't work with or without the code - It's just  function that that triggers an event inside of a react app. including the function in the above for the formatting.

Comment: Are you sure data-action is defined correctly? It's possible show your html code.

Comment: @motleydev In and of itself this ode should not break default functionality. You will need to show your HTML/etc. Also try a pure JS event handler.

Comment: Man, do I feel dumb - somehow in the inbetween when things were working and when I was implementing the new functionality - I removed my id tag on the section... Sorry for the wasted time.